# Spring AOP annotation based pointcuts for ElementType.TYPE?

Tags: spring, annotations, aop

I have a service implementation carrying a class-wide @Transactional annotation. I also have an aspect that uses the @Around advice to retry failed transactions. I'm now trying (for type-safety reasons) to make the pointcut definition annotation based:

```
@Around("@annotation(TransactionRetryable)")
```

TransactionRetryable.java:

```
    import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
    import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
    import java.lang.annotation.Target;
    import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;

    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
    public @interface TransactionRetryable {
    }
```

Service layer:

```
@Transactional
public class ... {
        @Override
        @TransactionRetryable
        public String forceError() {
            throw new RuntimeException(someNastyMessage);
        }
```

In that form, it only applies to method, not whole classes. However, the @Transactional annotation propagates from class level to each method. Is there a way to avoid putting the @TransactionRetryable annotation above each method and simply once above the class like the @Transactional annotation? Desired form:

```
@Transactional
@TransactionRetryable
public class ... {
        @Override
        public String forceError() {
            throw new RuntimeException(someNastyMessage);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pointcut would advise all public methods of a class annotated with `@TransactionRetryable`:

```
@Around("execution(public * *(..)) && within(@your.package.TransactionRetryable *)")
```

Comment: is there any possibility to access the annotation's argument value if it had some?

Comment: one can do pjp.getTarget().getClass().getAnnotation(TransactionRetryable.class).value()...